# Can't generate .htaccess [Symfony 4.3]

Tags: .htaccess, symfony

I would like to run my symfony project on Wampserver with a Vhost.
But for that, I need to create the .htaccess

So in my project, I did : `composer require symfony/apache-pack`

But in my /projectFolder/public, I haven't the .htaccess, I don't understand why

Answer (score 0):

What is the output of your command ? 
If you use a VHost, you don't need `.htaccess` since the job is done in your VHost config file

Answer (score 0):

Did you execute the recipe that comes with symfony/apache-pack?